# Access Jupyter notebook/lab running on a remote windows VM?

Tags: python, windows, azure, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I want to access Jupyter lab interface on my local machine browser (also running on windows) from a Jupyter server running on a remote Windows VM.

Is there any analogous technique to SSH tunneling in linux but for windows?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
I am not looking for remote desktop since the code autocomplete doesn't work and it's really unresponsive (and I think people can relate to other problems of coding on a remote desktop platform)

Answer (score 0):

Remote Desktop would be the easiest option.
If you need a browser, windows has ssh built in, but I think it has to be activated in the Windows options

Comment: Yes, currently I am using that but it's unresponsive and autocomplete in jupyter doesn't work!